# PrimeNg bar chart how do I hide the bar labels?

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I have a requirement to not show the labels for the bars AND squeeze the bars together, may be with 3 pixels between them?

I have tried just using blank labels and that has not worked.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide the label from xAxis and yAxis ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand you want to hide labels from xAixs and yAxis and also want to change the width of bar line. To do all these please use below code :

```
<p-chart type="bar" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>
```

In component initialize the option for chart:

```
    this.option1= {
       title: {
            display: true,
            text: '% Utilization',
            position: 'left'
          },
      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            show: true,
                            labelString: 'Value'
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero:true,
              max: 100,
              min: 0,
            }
                    }],
          xAxes: [{
            categoryPercentage:1,
            barPercentage:1,
            ticks: {
                display:false,
                beginAtZero:0
            }
        }]
      }
  }
```

To change the bar width use barThickness:4 and to hide lable use ticks property.
For more details check [Chartjs Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)

Comment: I added an image to the original question.Hoping that help explain my requirements

Comment: @reza I updated the answer. It will hide the x axis label and also distance between two bars. I have done this only for one dataset.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you. Do you have any thoughts on how to draw the vertical string for the Y-axis as shown in the picture?

Comment: @reza I updated the answer. here you go with it. Use title to show the text as you want.

Comment: I see it, thank you. Now that you have been so helpful, let me add one more question to this. So regardless of the data, is it possible for me to always show 0 to 100 for the yaxis? regardless of the data ?